# Does this look like mold? (Mold test negative)

Tags: mold, moisture, crawlspace

Recently had a mold test come back negative, despite me pulling a sample from white discolored crawlspace floor joist wood that is very close to an outside opening.

I was pretty confident this was mold given how humid this area gets when it rains, and how close this wood is to being exposed to the elements (crawlspace has several large gaps to outside).

The one thing that seems strange is that the background particulate density reading came back high. A high reading here seems to mean lower confidence in test results from the lab, so I'm not sure if this means that something with the test basically malfunctioned on my end or theirs.

I've also read that sometimes this can just be salt so I'm attaching a photo here in case that's helpful.

[image: wood]

Comment: if we could tell by looking at a photo there would not be mould tests.

Comment: Which bit is what you think might be mold ?  I think that it would be hard to stuff up this test.  Maybe you should trust it.

Comment: I would suggest that since you want this to be mold that you continue to send samples to different labs until you find one that tells you that yes, it is mold. Until that happens, I don't believe you'll be satisfied with any results.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the floor decking type and apparent age of the lumber I'd venture that the bridging slats are simply **reclaimed lumber** which was originally painted white for some other purpose. This was extremely common until around the 1970s, when our present "throwaway society" took hold and folks stopped recognizing the value of materials in favor of convenience and reduced quality. I've worked on remodels with actual train boxcar siding built into the home, painted signage and all, among other curiosities.

Additional evidence is the fact that some boards are almost completely covered, yet adjacent surfaces are completely free of white coloration. Mold doesn't usually roll like that.

Comment: Some of the old lumber in homes are extremely high quality. Couple years back I worked on a door and had to replace the entire door frame. The new frame I could lift the whole thing by myself. The old one I had to cut them in 1 meter logs because that 1 meter piece was substantially heavier than the ENTIRE new frame.

Answer (score 0):

Mold does not grow on surfaces like your pic shows.

You have a test that indicates negative for mold.

It would make more sense that some painted wood was used for the bracing of the flooring.

The while only shows on some of the braces and does not encroach to any of the other wood.

There are more indicators that the white stuff on the wood is not mold.

You need to embrace the reality that you don't have mold on that wood.